# Best way to create an association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I would like my `User` to be associated with specific `Email`'s, when they receive them.

In this way, I can look up an array of what emails they have received.

Originally, I was thinking of just creating a string field for the User table, and adding the unique ID to the array..

```
User.find(x).received_emails << Email.find(x).id
```

But there may be a better way to do this with associating models.

Recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check this link out:

[Rails association guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

It sounds like you're talking about a one to many sort of thing. If you use the association mechanism you'll get all the behavior you want, basically for free.

Comment: Thanks. This eventually helped me get through it all. I did a belongs_to_and_has_many relationship.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :received_emails, :class_name => 'Email'
end

User.find(x).received_emails << Email.find(y)
```

This approach would require adding a `user_id` column to the Email table.

You probably want to change this to a many-to-many association by adding a join table such as user_emails with a UserEmail model. That table would have `user_id` and `email_id` columns.

Comment: Hmm getting this `NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.<<
 from (irb):1`

Comment: I'm not sure this has to be polymorphic though. I just need the final result to be a User attribute array with several email id's in it. Sorry for sounding daft ;)

Comment: The typo in User has_many :received_emails is probably causing the NoMethodError.